# Check HANA edition with SQL?

Tags: hana, sap-cloud-platform

I have a JDBC connection to a SAP HANA database and I want to query whether it's a SAP HANA Cloud db or not. I know I can find the version with:

`SELECT VERSION FROM SYS.M_DATABASE;`

and this gives me 4.00.000.00.1608802791 for the cloud and 2.xx for my on-premise Dockerised version, but to avoid hard-coding version numbers everywhere, is there an equivalent query to, say, SQL Server's `SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('edition')`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `SELECT VALUE FROM M_HOST_INFORMATION WHERE KEY='build_branch'`

- On premise:   fa/hana2sp05
- In the cloud: fa/CE2020.36

You might also like `M_SYSTEM_OVERVIEW`, it has interestign informations such as the server start time.